# Can I change 'default' VPC to shared VPC in GCP instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vpc

I would like to know if it is possible to change **default** VPC to shared VPC in GCP in the network interface section on VM instance.

Thanks!

-Laurent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On instance creation, you can select your instance subnet to be a subnet of a Shared VPC, provided you have permission to use it. The zone you select for that instance must be in the same region as the selected subnet. The procedure is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#creating_an_instance_in_a_shared_subnet).

On the other hand, changing an existing instance to another VPC (shared or not) is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new compute instance which is similar to the existing one.  It will have the same configs, ssh keys, etc but you will need to rsync your data to the new instance.  Before you create the instance, you can change from default VPC to your custom VPC.

To do so, select the existing instance and then click `CREATE SIMILAR` button at top beside the `STOP` button.

On both instances install rsync.  I'm assuming you have Debian.

`$ sudo apt-get install rsync`

On the original instance  do this:

(I'm assuming you want to move a dir from your home dir on one box to the home dir on the second box.  Make sure you leave off the trailing slash, in case you use tab for auto completion.  Otherwise, it will transfer the source contents without directory name.)

`$ rsync -avz _some_dir_no_trailing_slash_ _user_name_@_cloned_instance_ip:.`

Since you have rsync on both systems, you can also pull directories from the original host to the newly cloned host.  If you have the same userid on both systems you can also omit the username specification.

On the newly cloned instance  do this:

`$ rsync -avz _original_instance_ip_:_some_dir_ .`